# Auto set view in Laravel

Tags: php, constructor, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I want to automatically set the view on a GET request in Laravel.  In the `BaseController` constructor I do this:

```
if (Request::server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'GET')
{
    $action = explode('@', Route::currentRouteAction());
    $view = explode('get', $action[1]);
    $view = strtolower(end($view));
    $controller = strtolower(explode('Controller', $action[0])[0]);

    $this->data['view'] = $controller . '.' . $view;
}
```

So basically if we make a request for `/some/page` it will look for a view file named `views/some/page.blade.php`.

Currently I set some data and other properties using `$this->data`.  So I build my data up before sending the view in each method:

```
$this->layout->with($this->data);
```

I end up having the above call in EVERY `GET` method and would like automate this whole thing.  The problem with using `$this->data` is that I can't access it any filters or other closures.  Is there a magic method or global data store I'm not using which I could call at the end of every request and just pump out the layout?

```
function afterEveryThing()
{
    $this->layout->with($this->data);
}
```

Something like the above in the `BaseController` or somewhere where I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Shooting from the hip here, but could you do your routing something like below.  This is a bad idea to use exactly as shown, but could be a starting point for what you are trying to do.

```
Route::any('{controller}/{method}', function($controller, $method) {

   $controllerName = ucfirst($controller) . "Controller";

   $controllerObject = new $controllerName;

   if (Request::server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'GET')
   {
          $controllerObject->$method();

          return View::make("$controller.$method")->with('data', $controllerObject->data);
   }
   else
   {
          return $controllerObject->$method();
   }

});
```

Comment: That's interesting approach, but basically takes out all the routing functionality from Laravel.

Comment: Right, it's not meant to be a line-for-line solution, just a starting point.  If you really wanted to automate, you could put all of your other routes before the above code.  Then the routing would prioritize all the other routes, then try to do an automatic route, then fail if nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

This will work (Laravel 4)

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    //
});
```

Or

In any version rename actions and implement magic method **__call** in controller class. For example for route to "IndexController@**index**" action:

*IndexController.php*

```
private function __call($method, $args) {

     ... look for a view...

    if (in_array('my_'.$method, self::$methods)) {
        //call to index translated to my_index
        call_user_func_array(array($this,'my_'.$method), $args); 
    } else {
        //error no action
        abort(404);
    }

     ... after every thing ...

}
public function my_index(Request $request)  {
    ... do action ...
}
```